# android DNS issue

Tags: android, networking, dns

I got a problem resolving dns in android. when I'm trying to resolve dns of an non-existing host, it resolves as 207.223.0.140. even if I logging into android shell and running ping command, DNS is resolved in the same way.
the same thing happens in emulator too.

how do I resolve real DNS of a host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to work this problem out is to use Google public DNS or OpenDNS servers to resolve host. there's no need to change WiFi DNS settings, just ask 8.8.8.8 to resolve hostname for you.
haven't had any issue since I start using these public DNS servers!

Answer (score 3):

That IP address is the IP address (or one of several IP addresses) for Comcast's search engine.

Your Android device is totally fine.

It's your Comcast DNS that is redirecting you to its search engine when it can't find a hostname.  (I've experienced this many times myself.)

Comment: You can probably set your DNS server in WiFi settings on the device to override Comcast's.  Google offers free public DNS.  Their servers are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: the thing is when I'm running ping from my PC (connected to the same router), it gives me an answer like: "Ping request could not find host", which seems to be correct...

Comment: small hack found to avoid this problem: open connection to the host using socket. if that fails with timeout, that host does not exists.